# How can I get rid of a space in my f-string?

Tags: python

I have an f-string with an if statement, but when I value is set to false, it leaves behind a space?  Here is what I have.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement
from sqlalchemy.sql import table
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler


class CreateView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name, selectable, replace=True):
        self.name = name
        self.selectable = selectable
        self.replace = replace


@compiler.compiles(CreateView)
def complile_create_view(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    replace_text = "OR REPLACE"
    return (
        f"""CREATE {replace_text if element.replace else ''} VIEW {element.name} """
        f"""AS {compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True)}"""
    )
```

To test this in my terminal,

```
from sqlalchemy import text
view_query = text("SELECT * FROM my_table")
create_view = CreateView('my_view', view_query, replace=False)
In [62]: print(str(create_view.compile()))
CREATE  VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table
```

If I set replace=True my DDL is fine.  How do I get rid of that extra space between CREATE and VIEW?

Comment: Why does it matter? It's still valid. If you're getting errors, it's not because of the extra space.

Comment: yes the DDL is valid since sql will still process it, I just want it to be perfect.

Comment: If you wanted it to be perfect, you wouldnt be using `f` strings like this to build the string. My SQL Injection sense is tingling, but I can't give a concrete example.

Comment: Correct, I can build the string other way, I am just trying to see if I could.

Comment: Looking at the answers, this is _totally_ ugly. I can't think of a reasonable scenario to require this. That's not to say that they are _wrong_ but I just can't see what problem is solved through this.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

The first option is to take the space out of your string and add it to the replacement:

```
f"CREATE{' ' + replace_text if element.replace else ''} VIEW {element.name}"
```

Obviously a bit ugly. Or place double spaces with a single space after formatting:

```
f"CREATE {replace_text if element.replace else ''} VIEW {element.name}".replace('  ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you not using replace_text, so simply move spaces to its value and change your `else` to output space instead of nothing:

```
@compiler.compiles(CreateView)
def complile_create_view(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    replace_text = " OR REPLACE "
    return (
        f"""CREATE{replace_text if element.replace else ' '}VIEW {element.name} """
        f"""AS {compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True)}"""
    )
```

Comment: This will result in _no_ space after `CREATE`. For example, if `replace_text = 'foo'`, you'll get `CREATEfooVIEW ...`

Comment: while this works, this seems like the kind of thing that will absolutely kill someone whos trying to maintain it 5 years later. I noticed and refer to the mandatory whitespace around `replace_text`. *Ah well, poor interns*. Perhaps add the whitespaces around replace_text separately before the return statement.

Comment: there're are comments you can use to leave note for future maintainers